# Add a project to tfs without a solution

Tags: tfs

I want to add a project to TFS without a solution?
Do I have to create a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely just add project to TFS, without adding the solution. 
Just select that project and click File->Source Control->Add selected projects to Source Control